# MySQL join 3 tables and find "missing" rows in one table

Tags: mysql, join, not-exists

I have 3 tables in MySQL and I need to find all instances where a user does not have a specific widget.

Example:

```
Users
tenant_id user_id user_name
1         1       Bob
1         2       Fred
1         3       John
1         4       Tom

Widgets
tenant_id widget_id widget_name
1         1         Red
1         2         Blue
1         3         Green
1         4         Black

Usage
tenant_id user_id widget_id
1         1       1
1         1       2 
1         1       4
1         2       2
1         2       3
1         2       4
1         3       1
1         3       2
1         3       3
1         3       4
1         4       1
1         4       2
1         4       3

Missing in table three are:
user_name widget_name
Bob       Green
Fred      Red
Tom       Black
```

The query I am trying to use is:

```
SELECT
  user_name, widget_name
FROM
  users left join widgets on users.tenant_id=widgets.tenant_id
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM usage WHERE user_id = users.user_id AND widget_id = widgets.widget_id
  ) and users.tenant_id=1
```

When the query completes it brings back a huge list of usernames and widget names but many hundreds more than I expect.

I am not sure if the join is wrong or if I need to do some sort of grouping on the result?

Comment: What result are you getting?  Please include that in your answer or set up a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the idea behind this type of query.  First generate all possible combinations of users and widgets.  Then filter out the ones that exist:

```
select u.user_name, w.widget_name
from users u join
     widgets w
     on u.tenant_id = w.tenant_id
where not exists (select 1
                  from usage us
                  where us.user_id = u.user_id and us.widget_id = w.widget_id and
                        us.tenant_id = u.tenant_id
                 ) and
      u.tenant_id = 1;
```

I think your logic is missing the `tenant_id` in the `usage` table.  However, I'm not sure that makes a big difference.

Comment: I used this and it gives the correct result - the other thing I notice is you are using join but I was using left join, might that make a difference?

Comment: @bhttoan . . . If you have users with no widgets at all, then that would explain the difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cartesian product  and some of inner join

```
select b.user_name, c.widget_name 
from 
( select u.user_id, w.widget_id
from Users as u, Widgets as w
where (u.user_id, w.widget_id) not in (select user_id, widget_id 
                                          from Usage)) as a
inner join Users as b on a.user_id = b.user_id 
inner join Widgets as c on a.widget_id = c.widget_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one, worked for me.

```
select w.widget_name, u.user_name 
from widgets w join users u on w.tenant_id = u.tenant_id
where (w.widget_name, u.user_name ) not in 
             (select w.widget_name, u.user_name
              from widgets w join `usage` us on us.widget_id = w.widget_id
              join users u on u.user_id = us.user_id);
```